Are vintage mercury fever thermometers fully sealed?
I'm just curious about the mercury thermometers that were manufactured in the past for measuring fever.  Is the glass tube completely sealed?  (i.e. are there any holes at the top like a release valve in case the temperature gets too high?)
I actually have one of these thermometers from Italy, probably manufactured before 1970's.  I examined it closely with a magnifier and could not find any evidence of any tiny hole at the top.
My concern is if the temperature is too high (past max reading) that the mercury would escape and expose the user.


Mercury evaporates and turns into an extremely toxic vapor at room temperature, so not having that tube completely sealed would be a bit of a problem.

@CareyGregory oh ok, I didn't realize that.  that makes sense.  I suppose if it did have a hole, it may have vaporized after all these years.

Or simply leaked out. I know from personal experience (as a child) that if you hold one of those under hot running water, what will happen is it will pop and all the mercury will be expelled. There's no way that could ever happen with proper usage since the max temperature on those things as I recall is well into the "you're dead" range.
